# UITableView with first character of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

My array contains: Barney Eskin, Aaron Hoe, Dale Perella, Earl Bruice, Fabian Oleski, Calvin Zinnes

Question 1 : How can I create a `UITableView` having an initial circle created with a different image and the first letter of the string in it. (as shown in the pic below)

[image]

Question 2 : How can I add a swipe gesture to open a menu and perform an action on it, like in the following image:

[image]

Comment: I will give you solution on Monday.Can you wait till Monday?

Comment: I will bring you what you expect.

Comment: sure ,for the accepted answer by the way i create it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party library for swipe-able cells. There are many libraries that provide this functionality, but this is the best

1.[MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)

2.[SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)

For the first character, you can create a custom `UIView` and use `UILabel` inside it and you can fetch the first character from the string like this:

```
if ([string hasPrefix:@"0"] && [string length] > 1) {
    string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: i have to display menu under the cell

Comment: menu will be static or dynamic for all cells?

Comment: dynamic according to condition means if object at index 1 can only have delete option, index 2 have both delete and edit option etc

Comment: then you can use custom view on cell

Comment: You have to design manual view in cell and maintain it with with gesture